# How to remove all the elements other than the last element in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html form as follows

```
<div class="control-group" id="fields">
    <label for="">Use this section to add as many execution steps as you would like for this test case.</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <form role="form" autocomplete="off" id="formStep">
            <div class="entry input-group col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                <input class="form-control stepFields" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="test step">
            </div>
            <div class="entry input-group col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                <input class="form-control stepFields" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="test step">
            </div>
            <div class="entry input-group col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                <input class="form-control stepFields" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="test step">
            </div>
            <div class="entry input-group col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                <input class="form-control stepFields" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="test step">
            </div>
        </form>
        <br>

    </div>
</div>
```

and I have the following JS (Jquery)

```
    $('.controls form')
        .not($(this).children('.entry').last()[0])
        .remove();
```

What I would like to do is to remove all the divs with the class name `entry`  *except the last one* ?

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: `this` isn't the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `find()` and `not()`

Try the following

```
 $('.controls form').find('.entry').not(':last').remove();
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/grgf9yub/)

Comment: Thanks @madalin - that solved it.. I will mark the answer in another 12 minutes as per SO.. thanks once again